# I am working on angular 8 when i display image in gallery page ,then image not shown , how can solve it?

Tags: angular8

Angular 8 image not shown 
image included in assets folder

here is my code

```
<img src="assets/image/gallery/4.jpg"  alt="Recent Work" class="img-responsive" />
```

in angular.json folder

"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets"
],

Comment: please make sure that the desired file 4.jpg is in the location => "src/assets/image/gallery/4.jpg"

Comment: yes 4.jpg is => "src/assets/image/gallery/4.jpg"

Comment: did you get a 404 error in console, that shows the image can't found at the path?

Comment: yes but path is all right ,image included ,then how i get error

Comment: in other page same image shown perfectly ..but this page got error not banner image shown or not gallery image

Comment: if the same path works fine in another page, please reserve (ng serve) your angular app (this is not actually a solution but some time some file changes will loose the tracking of ng serve)

Comment: how can solve it

Comment: did that helped you?

Comment: not solved is show same error ?